# Displaying unicode text in Rave Reports on Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, unicode, reporting, delphi-2009, rave-reports

I am in the process of porting a Delphi 2006 app to Delphi 2009. Out of the box support for unicode has been easy - almost no work required. Most 3rd party controls already have Delphi 2009 updates available.

Rave Reports (latest version 7.6.1, available [here](http://cc.codegear.com/item/26089)) has also been updated, but I cannot seem to get it to correctly display RTF text containing Japanese characters. In Delphi 2006, I loaded RTF to the DataMemo component in a RVCustomConnection's OnGetRow event by reading the RTF from a screen control (TLMDRichEdit) using streams and then doing a CustomConnection.WriteBlobData.

In the report output, any RTF text now shows up as a series of rectanges and % signs. No readable text. All other text (displayed using Text and DataText components) displays correctly.

Does anyone have any experience on how to get RTF containing unicode to display correctly? Is it even supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone from Nevrona cares to comment, I am concluding that it is not (yet) possible.

Answer (score 1):

I used this...it seemed to work with Dephi XE's built in RAVE package...

```
Procedure TfrmMain.RaveCustomConnectionGetRow                  (         Connection: TRvCustomConnection);
Var
  MemoString : String;
  Index      : Integer;
  Size       : Integer;
  Buffer     : PAnsiChar;

Begin


  { Init MemoString }
  MemoString := '';

  For Index := 0 To DataList.Count - 1 Do Begin
    MemoString := MemoString + DataList.Strings [Index] + #13#10;
  End; { For }

  { Set the Size (Unicode) and Buffer }
  Size := Length (MemoString) * 2;
  Buffer := PAnsiChar (MemoString);

  { Send the data over as a Blob object to RAVE }
  Connection.WriteBlobData (Buffer^, Size);

End; { RaveCustomConnectionGetRow Procedure }
```

Comment: Thanks for the update - I had this issue a loooong time ago. I remember looking around at the time and no-one else really had a solution (both here and on other sites). Your code sample will no-doubt help someone out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even without unicode the RTF printing in Rave reports is broken (adds rectangles at the end of the lines). New version 7.6.2 has not fixed this,,,

F&^%ing pathetic from Codegear (or what is it called now) and Nevrona...

Comment: I ended up using FastReports. It was quick and painless to change over to it, and it is Unicode friendly.